# Should try-catch-finally be used instead of SemaphoreReleaseOnlyOnce in rocketmq invokeOnewayImpl?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, rocketmq

**Should try-catch-finally be used instead of SemaphoreReleaseOnlyOnce in rocketmq invokeOnewayImpl?**

**origin code**

```
    public void invokeOnewayImpl(final Channel channel, final RemotingCommand request, final long timeoutMillis)
        throws InterruptedException, RemotingTooMuchRequestException, RemotingTimeoutException, RemotingSendRequestException {
        // 标记为单向发送
        request.markOnewayRPC();
        boolean acquired = this.semaphoreOneway.tryAcquire(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (acquired) {
            final SemaphoreReleaseOnlyOnce once = new SemaphoreReleaseOnlyOnce(this.semaphoreOneway);
            try {
                channel.writeAndFlush(request).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) f -> {
                    once.release();
                    if (!f.isSuccess()) {
                        log.warn("send a request command to channel <" + channel.remoteAddress() + "> failed.");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                once.release();
                log.warn("write send a request command to channel <" + channel.remoteAddress() + "> failed.");
                throw new RemotingSendRequestException(RemotingHelper.parseChannelRemoteAddr(channel), e);
            }
        }//....
    }
```

**new code**

```
    public void invokeOnewayImpl(final Channel channel, final RemotingCommand request, final long timeoutMillis)
        throws InterruptedException, RemotingTooMuchRequestException, RemotingTimeoutException, RemotingSendRequestException {
        // 标记为单向发送
        request.markOnewayRPC();
        boolean acquired = this.semaphoreOneway.tryAcquire(timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if (acquired) {
            try {
                channel.writeAndFlush(request).addListener((ChannelFutureListener) f -> {
                    if (!f.isSuccess()) {
                        log.warn("send a request command to channel <" + channel.remoteAddress() + "> failed.");
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.warn("write send a request command to channel <" + channel.remoteAddress() + "> failed.");
                throw new RemotingSendRequestException(RemotingHelper.parseChannelRemoteAddr(channel), e);
            } finally {
                this.semaphoreOneway.release();
            }
        }//...
    }
```

Is it necessary to use SemaphoreReleaseOnlyOnce？

Is try-catch-finally more suitable？

I hope someone can answer my doubts.